# How to make Python script developed in Spyder IDE executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, executable

I wrote a script in Spyder IDE, but in order for clients to use it, I would like to make it easier to run it then opening Anaconda and then Spyder and running it from there.

The reason I used Spyder was because it allowed me to use many modules that otherwise wouldn't be allowed on company stations.

I researched a lot but could not find a way to do this.

I was thinking of enveloping the script in a batch file and running it. I tried updating the python script to look for modules in the Anaconda default directories:

```
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python37.zip)
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs)
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib)
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3)
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages)
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32)
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib)
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin)
sys.path.insert(1, C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions)
```

When running the script in Windows cmd, I got these errors when importing pandas module, so there is more to using Spyder then just accessing those modules (I couldn't figure out what):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 32, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    import warnings
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\warnings.py", line 494
    f"coroutine '{coro.__qualname__}' was never awaited\n"
```

Another approach I tried was using **pyinstaller**, but that is not available for us and I cannot install it from the website.

Is there a way of running the python script and using all the modules offered by Anaconda without going through Spyder?

Answer (score 1):

Also try [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It'll give you both an executable and settings for that, like icon or no-console. first go to the directory where your `.py` file is and run the below command:

```
pyinstaller script.py --onefile
```

Before this, you'll need to install that python module:

```
python* -m pip install pyinstaller
```

Where `*` is your specific python version, if you have multiple installed.
The first command will give you `dist` folder, here is where your executable is placed. and the `script.spec` file is your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)? It's a great tool that does exactly what you're asking for.

Also look into [cython](https://cython.org/). It's a lot easier to generate an executable from C code, and you'll get a performance boost as well.